# EF Core AddRange and entities with duplicate keys

Tags: entity-framework-core

I have a use case where a third party provides an enumeration of items that I wish to merge into a database using EF Core. There are use cases where the third party provides an item with the **same key more than once in the enumeration**.

| Id | Account | LastPayment |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | ABC123 | 1/1/2021 |
| 23456 | BCD234 | 2/1/2021 |
| 12345 | ABC123 | 2/1/2021 |

Ideally, I would like BOTH updates to 12345 to take place (we audit history in the data tier).

I get an error when attempting to add 12345 twice to the same context. Code POC is:

```cs
[Fact]
public async Task HandlesDuplicateKeys()
{
    var services = new ServiceCollection()
        .AddDbContext<ItemContext>(options => options.UseInMemoryDatabase(Guid.NewGuid().ToString()))
        .BuildServiceProvider();

    var items = new List<ItemA>()
    {
        new ItemA() { Id = 1, A = "Foo" },
        new ItemA() { Id = 1, A = "Bar" }
    };

    using (var context = services.GetRequiredService<ItemContext>())
    {
        context.AList.AddRange(items);
        await context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}

public class ItemA
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? A { get; set; }
}

public class ItemContext : DbContext
{
    public RepositoryContext(DbContextOptions<RepositoryContext> options) : base(options)
    { }

    public DbSet<ItemA> AList { get; set; }
}
```

yields:

> Message:
> System.InvalidOperationException : The instance of entity type 'ItemA' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values.

What's the appropriate way to manage this use case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The EF team was kind enough to [provide a solution](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/24780) which I've tweaked below.

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Saves a range of items, handing duplicates. Returns the number of items saved.
/// <see href="https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/24780"/>
/// </summary>
/// <param name="dbset">DbSet to save <paramref name="items"/> to.</param>
/// <param name="items">Items to save. May contains items with same key(s).</param>
/// <param name="context">DbContext that DbSet belongs to. If not specified, it will be fetched via <see cref="ICurrentDbContext"/>.</param>
/// <param name="cancellationToken">Cancellation token.</param>
public static async ValueTask<int> SaveRangeAsync<T>(this DbSet<T> dbset, IEnumerable<T> items, DbContext? context = null, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default) where T: class
{
    var count = 0;
    context = context ?? dbset.GetService<ICurrentDbContext>().Context;

    var keys = context.Model.FindEntityType(typeof(T)).FindPrimaryKey().Properties.Select(e => e.Name);

    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        var existing = context.SameOrDefault(item, keys);

        // If we hit a duplicate key, we need to save and then resume adding.
        if (existing != null)
        {
            count += await context.SaveChangesAsync();
            existing.CurrentValues.SetValues(item);
        }
        else
            context.Add(item);
        if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            break;
    }
    count += await context.SaveChangesAsync();
    return count;
}

/// <summary>
/// Finds the first <see cref="EntityEntry"/> with keys matching <paramref name="item"/>.
/// </summary>
public static EntityEntry<T>? SameOrDefault<T>(this DbContext context, T item, IEnumerable<string> keys) where T: class
{
    var entry = context.Entry(item);
    foreach (var entity in context.ChangeTracker.Entries<T>())
    {
        bool mismatch = false;
        foreach (var key in keys)
        {
            if (!Equals(entity.Property(key).CurrentValue, entry.Property(key).CurrentValue))
            {
                mismatch = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!mismatch)
            return entity;
    }
    return default;
}
```

Usage:

```cs
[Fact]
public async Task HandlesDuplicateKeys()
{
    var services = new ServiceCollection()
        .AddDbContext<RepositoryContext>(options => options.UseInMemoryDatabase(Guid.NewGuid().ToString()))
        .BuildServiceProvider();

    var items = new List<ItemA>()
    {
        new ItemA() { Id = 1, A = "Foo" },
        new ItemA() { Id = 1, A = "Bar" }
    };

    using (var context = services.GetRequiredService<RepositoryContext>())
    {
        var count = await context.AList.SaveRangeAsync(items);
        Assert.Equal(2, count);
    }
}
```

Thanks [ajcvickers](https://github.com/ajcvickers)!